# I'm getting 3 C4703 errors on variables I think I've initialized correctly and I'm not sure what I'm missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing a project for a class and I have to have my program read arithmetic expressions from an input file and evaluate them. Unfortunately whenever I try to implement my ternaryCondition.h header my debug throws three

> subexpression.cpp(75):error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'first' used
>
> subexpression.cpp(75):error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'second' used
>
> subexpression.cpp(75):error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'third' used

This is my second time working with C++ so I feel like I'm just missing something entirely.

I've tried disabling /sdl checks but when I do that I find that my program can no longer read line by line through my input file and evaluate the expressions.

This is the subexpressions.cpp thats throwing the error up to the 75th line where the error occurs:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "operand.h"
#include "plus.h"
#include "minus.h"
#include "times.h"
#include "divide.h"
#include "greaterThan.h"
#include "lessThan.h"
#include "equal.h"
#include "and.h"
#include "or.h"
#include "negation.h"
#include "ternaryCondition.h"


#include <sstream>


SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right)

{

    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;

}

SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third)
{
    this->first = first;
    this->second = second;
    this->third = third;
}

SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* left)
{
    this->left = left;
}

Expression* SubExpression::parse(stringstream& in)

{
    Expression* left;
    Expression* right;
    Expression* first;
    Expression* second;
    Expression* third;
    char operation, paren;
    bool isTernary = false;

    left = Operand::parse(in);
    cin >> operation;
    right = Operand::parse(in);
    if (operation == ':')
    {
        first = left;
        second = right;
        left = Operand::parse(in);
        cin >> operation;
        right = Operand::parse(in);
        if (operation == '?')
        {
            third = right;
            isTernary = true;
        }
    }
    cin >> paren;
    if (isTernary == true)
    {
        return new TernaryCondition(first, second, third); 
//THE LINE ABOVE IS LINE 75 WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING THROWN
    }
    switch (operation)
    {
```

And this is the ternaryCondition.h header in case that could be causing issues:

```
class TernaryCondition : public SubExpression
{
public:
    TernaryCondition(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third) :
        SubExpression(first, second, third)
    {
    }
    int evaluate()
    {
        return third->evaluate() ? first->evaluate() : second->evaluate(); 
    }
};
```

The point of this part of my code is so that the program can calculate expressions like

( ( ( z < ( 50 + aa ) ) & ( bb ! ) ) * ( ( 3 / cc ) | ( 1 : 0 ? ( z > aa ) ) , z = 4 , aa = 2 , bb = 4 , cc = 2 ;

I'm sorry if I submitted this in a improper format, this is my first time posting.

ADDED THE subexpression.h HEADER FILE:

```
class SubExpression : public Expression
{
public:
    SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right);
    SubExpression(Expression* left);
    SubExpression(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third);
    static Expression* parse(stringstream& in);

protected:
    Expression* left;
    Expression* right;
    Expression* first;
    Expression* second;
    Expression* third;
};
```

Comment: *throwing the error up to the 75th* -- ok, let me count -- 1, 2, 3, 4,... forget it.  Which line is "line 75"?

Comment: `SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right)` -- You really should be initializing **all** of your member variables, not just the ones you think are being used.  If you now construct a `SubExpression` this way, you have uninitialized variables in your object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see now why I was told not to post entire files. I added a comment near the end of my first block of code as I cut it off there. The reason I submitted so much is because I'm not sure if I'm missing a set of code higher up.

Comment: The constructor that takes two arguments fails to initialize "first", "second" and "third".  Please post the `SubExpression` class, since there are probably more members that fail to be initialized.  Conversely, the `SubExpression` constructor that takes 3 arguments fails to initialize "left" and "right", and the single argument constructor fails to initialize everything except for one member variable.

Comment: I have added the subexpression.h class. Thank you for your patience with my sloppy code. Would it be better to create a constructor that initializes all of my arguments at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize all of the member of your `SubExpression` class, and not have them in an inconsistent, uninitialized state.

Here is what initialization should look like:

```
class SubExpression : public Expression
{
public:
    SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right);
    SubExpression(Expression* left);
    SubExpression(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third);
    static Expression* parse(stringstream& in);

protected:
    Expression* left;
    Expression* right;
    Expression* first;
    Expression* second;
    Expression* third;
};
```

---

```
SubExpression::Subexpression(Expression* left_, Expression* right_) : left(left_), right(right_), first(nullptr), second(nullptr), third(nullptr)
{}

SubExpression::Subexpression(Expression* left_) : left(left_), right(nullptr), first(nullptr), second(nullptr), third(nullptr)
{}

SubExpression::Subexpression(Expression* first_, Expression* second_, Expression* third_) : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), first(first_), second(second_), third(third_)
{}
```

Second, due to the pointers not being initialized, you will have a much harder time debugging a program that uses one of those uninitialized values.  If at the very least, the pointer is set to `nullptr`, you have a better chance of fixing any errors.

---

Another potential reason for the warning is this code in the `parse` function:

```
Expression* left;
Expression* right;
Expression* first;
Expression* second;
Expression* third;
```

In the `parse` function, you are relying on the `if()` statement to be true to set the pointers above.  Don't do that -- the same thing applies here that applies to your class members -- initialize all of those variables to `nullptr`.

Comment: Are the bottom 3 lines of code under the semicolon what I should have my constructors in my subexpression.cpp file look like? Sorry if my question is ignorant, I was attempting to make my constructors as they were taught in my course. When I attempt to make my constructors the code you provided it throws errors for all 3 of them.

Comment: Those 3 lines are what your constructors should look like.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your advice! I am still facing the same set of error C4703s even with these new constructors though, they're still being thrown off the same line.

Comment: Well you should initialize all of your variables -- don't rely on the `if` logic to help the compiler.  The compiler has no idea what path your code will take if the input is generated at run-time, thus the warning.

Comment: Adding nullptr to those variables fixed that problem! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Creating own parsers is laudable. It will help you understand better how the compilers work.

Here it seems your error gets triggered on the following line

```
    return new TernaryCondition(first, second, third);
```

While logically speaking, if the **istertiary** is true then **first, second, and third** should be initialized already. Either the complier gets confused or the line #75 Is somewhere else. If the complier gets confused it is because the initialization happens within a conditional block, so it might never happen. And then after you try to use the variables , at least without checking the logical dependencies, could be uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

`first`, `second`, and `third` are both class members and local variables within `parse()`. The former are indeed uninitialized unless operation == ':'. When used without `this->`, the compiler picks the local ones.

Name collision, that's all.

Comment: I have removed the this-> statements in accordance with the constructors that PaulMcKenzie provided in the answer section but I still get the same errors on debug. I'm just not sure what I'm missing.